# What is the right preposition with "page"

Tags: prépositions

I am quite sure you should always, or nearly always use “à la page”, or maybe “dans la page”, which is less common. But in my textbook, I've found such a sentence: “Lisez le texte de la page neuf”.

Why do we use “de” in this case and can we use a different preposition?

Answer (score 4):

There is no single "right" preposition.

Just like in English, the ones to use primarily depends on what you want to say (e.g. of, in, on/about, around, before/after, from, according to, ...)

*- Lis le texte **de** la page 9.

- Le personnage apparaît pour la première fois **à** la page 9.

- J'ai fait un commentaire **sur** la page 9.

- Il en parle **vers** la page 9.

- C'est écrit **avant/après** la page 9.

- On s'en doute **dès** la page 9.

- **D'après** la page 9 de la notice, c'est ce qu'il faut faire.

- ...*

Comment: +1! Rien que pour l'entrée en matière! Car c'est ça le vrai droit!... il n'y a pas de devoir! Tout au plus des nuances de correction... L'éloquence de tes points de suspension finaux m'épargnent même le besoin d'en suggérer d'autres! +2 donc!

Answer (score -1):

You can use both "à" and "de" but « de » is more common.

- la note de/à la page x
- l'illustration de/à la page x

« De » can be confusing as in the case when what is meant by « de » is not « found at » but « attribute of ».

- l'illustration de la page de couverture (*this does not mean "the illustration found on the cover" but "the illustration  that decorates the cover page", in current English, "the cover illustration".*)